# How to reduce the build time of Docker image layer in GitHub Actions?

Tags: python, cache, git, docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile with `ubuntu:22.04` as a base image and a manual Python installation(specific version i.e., 3.11.1) layer which takes a long time.

Approach 1:

1. Build a *custom_image* with ubuntu:22.04 as a base image and a manual Python installation layer.
2. Create another Dockerfile with *custom_image* as the base image and add other layers of the image
3. Cache the *custom_image* using `docker/build-push-action@v5` action

Approach 2:

1. Use `ubuntu-latest` runner with `actions/setup-python` GitHub action with a specific version.
2. Once Python setup is successful, copy Python binaries to Docker context like `cp -r $RUNNER_TOOL_CACHE/Python/3.11.1/* Python/3.11.1`
3. Copy these files into docker and update the `PATH` variable like

   ```
   # Copy Python binaries from the GitHub Actions workflow
   COPY Python /opt/Python

   # Update PATH to include the copied Python binaries
   ENV PATH="/opt/Python/3.11.1/x64/bin:/opt/Python/3.11.1/x64:${PATH}"

   # Set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include the copied shared libraries
   ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/Python/3.11.1/x64/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"
   ```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 ubuntu:22.04 as base

USER root

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY ZscalerRootCertificate-2048-SHA256.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ZscalerRootCertificate-2048-SHA256.crt

# Copy Python binaries from the GitHub Actions workflow
COPY Python /opt/Python

# Update PATH to include the copied Python binaries
ENV PATH="/opt/Python/3.11.1/x64/bin:/opt/Python/3.11.1/x64:${PATH}"

# Set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include the copied shared libraries
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/python/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"

# Fail soon than later, if python wasn't installed
RUN python --version

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y software-properties-common ca-certificates && \
    update-ca-certificates


RUN python -m pip install -U pip

RUN python3.11 -m pip install --no-cache-dir --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org -r requirements/core-requirements.txt
```

GitHub workflow:

```
name: Docker Image CI

env:
  CONTAINER_NAME: my-use-case

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

concurrency:
  group: ${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.head_ref || github.run_id }}
  cancel-in-progress: true

permissions:
  id-token: write
  contents: write

jobs:
  integration-tests:
    name: Integration Test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: View directory files
        run: |
          pwd
          echo "$PATH"

      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: "3.11.1"

      - name: Copy Python binaries to Docker context
        run: |
          mkdir -p Python/3.11.1
          cp -r $RUNNER_TOOL_CACHE/Python/3.11.1/* Python/3.11.1

      - name: View directory files
        run: |
          ls -lhR
          echo "$PATH"

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python --version
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip

      - name: View directory files
        run: |
          ls -lhR

      - name: Build & push docker image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          context: .
          push: false
          tags: ${{ env.CONTAINER_NAME }}:${{ github.run_number }}
          file: ./Dockerfile
```

Comment: Please do not edit the question, especially the code, after an answer has been posted. Changing the question may cause answer invalidation. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. [What to do after the question has been answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @pacmaninbw Thanks for suggesting. I asked new question instead of editing and accepted the closest answer. The new question is [how-to-reduce-the-build-time-cache-docker-image-layer-in-subsequent-github-action-runs](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/288337/200778)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- > ```
  > COPY ZscalerRootCertificate-2048-SHA256.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ZscalerRootCertificate-2048-SHA256.crt
  > ```

  The command here runs, presumably, on a file.
  When Docker performs the copy, Docker compares the file with the file in the cache.
  If the files are deemed to be the same then Docker skips the step and moves on using the previously cached image.

  As such if you have the above `COPY` before any other `COPY`s then the copy will be cached.
- > ```
  > COPY . /app
  > COPY Python /opt/Python
  > ```

  Copying directories to the docker build scope invalidates the cache. And acts as if the files are not the same, *even if the files are the same*.

  If you can change the action to be copying a file (say a `.zip` or `.tar.bz`) then you can cache the interaction.
- > ```
  > RUN apt-get update && \
  >     apt-get upgrade -y && \
  >     apt-get install -y software-properties-common ca-certificates && \
  >     update-ca-certificates
  > ```

  I don't see why the above `RUN` command needs to be below the `COPY` operations. If you don't want to copy an archive then you probably can move the command higher to allow caching to happen.
- > ```
  > RUN python -m pip install -U pip
  > RUN python3.11 -m pip install --no-cache-dir --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org -r requirements/core-requirements.txt
  > ```

  Likewise I'm not sure you need to run the commands after any of the `COPY` commands.
  You can have a single `COPY` command for the requirements, and possibly any configs you need.

  Additionally I normally position the commands in a builder which focuses on building a `venv`.
  I use the standardized `python` image for the version I'm building against. I then copy the files to optimize caching and then just have a fat 'copy everything and don't care about caching' core.

  ```
  # Not version pinned, doesn't work
  FROM python:3 AS builder
  WORKDIR /build

  RUN python -m pip install virtualenv
  RUN python -m virtualenv venv
  COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
  RUN venv/bin/python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
  # invalidates the cache
  COPY . .
  RUN venv/bin/python -m pip install .


  FROM nginx/unit:1.26.1-python3.10
  EXPOSE 80
  EXPOSE 443
  VOLUME ["/app/.data"]
  WORKDIR /app
  ENV PATH /app/venv/bin:$PATH

  # no caching needed
  COPY nginx_config.json /docker-entrypoint.d/config.json
  COPY --from=builder /build/venv venv  # copy the venv from the builder
  RUN chown unit:unit -R .data venv
  ```

  In more intricate builders I have copied configs and SSH keys to the builder and know the files won't be in the final image. Reducing the clean-up steps.

Comment: Thanks for the details on how the position of commands impacts caching. Any good resource would you recommend to get a deeper understanding of docker commands and best practices? If I place Python manual installation commands at the start, will it get cached? I will update my post with the Python manual installation command soon.

Comment: Is there any way that I can cache the manual Python install command in the Dockerfile in subsequent CI runs GitHub actions?

Comment: As per community rules, I have to ask this as new question, can you please help with that? The new question is [how-to-reduce-the-build-time-cache-docker-image-layer-in-subsequent-github-action-runs?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/288337/200778)

Comment: @shaikmoeed When I learnt the Dockerfile commands I partially rewrote the [Dockerfile reference page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) to have both my own cheat sheet, and to fasten my learning. From memory the Docker reference page didn't go too much into caching, so through trial and error I figured out which commands to place where to minimize cache invalidation. `RUN` commands only invalidate the cache if the command changes -- so treat the command as never invalidate the cache. Then you just want file `COPY` commands at the top, followed by `RUN` and then dir `COPY`s.

Answer (score 3):

We have two goals for a speedy build of a docker image:

1. small image
2. small diffs

I notice you're not yet using
[layers](https://vsupalov.com/5-tips-to-speed-up-docker-build).
You want to.

---

You start out with LTS Jammy Jellyfish as the `base` layer, good.
Although you might prefer an image with the Alpine distribution,
as they have gone to some trouble to pare its functionality
to the bone. If there's an apt package installed which you never use,
then copying its bits around just costs us more time.

After the base layer, we don't take advantage of any additional
[CoW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) layers.

Depending on your requirements, you may or may not have
to ask `apt` to update and upgrade on every CI/CD build.
Doing that daily or weekly might suffice.

On top of `base`, use `FROM base as python` to build a `python` layer that
includes interpreter plus pip-installed libraries.
Again, up-to-the-minute fresh libraries might not
be a requirement for every build.
Ideally we would see a stable hash for this layer
over multiple builds, indicating no work needed to be done.

On top of `python`, build an `app` layer
that includes the checked-out feature branch.

Our goal in all this is to minimize diffs
within a layer from one build to the next,
so the `apt` and `pip` steps can complete
within a couple seconds because there is
very little to do, few diffs since last time.

Use `RUN date` or other timing measurements
to help you assess whether a given stage is
doing more work than you believe it should
have to do.
Rapid docker builds *are* possible.

Comment: "build an `app` layer" are the layers metaphors, or does Docker contain a layering mechanism?

Comment: If I understand correctly, I need to create three stages `base, python, app` and most of the commands in the first two stages will be cached. And I have updated my Dockerfile in the post with a manual Python install command, is there any way that I can cache that command in subsequent CI runs?

Comment: I think this answer conflates two docker concepts, namely layers and stages. Each docker command in a Dockerfile will introduce a new layer into the produced image. These layers are cached aggressively during build and pull operations. You can separate a build process into stages, i.e. groups of layers, which can additionally optimize the build but the primary use is to reduce image size by separating buildtime environment from runtime environment.

Comment: As per community rules, I have to ask this as new question, can you please help with that? The new question is [how-to-reduce-the-build-time-cache-docker-image-layer-in-subsequent-github-action-runs?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/288337/200778)