# How to reduce the build time/cache Docker image layer in subsequent GitHub Actions runs?

Tags: python, cache, git, docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile with `ubuntu:22.04` as a base image and a manual Python installation(specific version i.e., 3.11.1) layer which takes a long time. How to cache this manual Python installation layer in the docker image in subsequent CI runs in GitHub actions?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 ubuntu:22.04 as base

USER root

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

COPY ZscalerRootCertificate-2048-SHA256.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ZscalerRootCertificate-2048-SHA256.crt

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y software-properties-common ca-certificates && \
    update-ca-certificates

RUN mkdir /python && cd /python && \
        wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.1/Python-3.11.1.tgz && \
       tar -zxvf Python-3.11.1.tgz && \
       cd Python-3.11.1 && \
       ls -lhR && \
       ./configure --enable-optimizations && \
       make install && \
       rm -rf /python

# Fail soon than later, if python wasn't installed
RUN python --version

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN python -m pip install -U pip

RUN python3.11 -m pip install --no-cache-dir --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org -r requirements/core-requirements.txt

CMD ["gunicorn", "main:app", "--workers", "2", "--worker-class", "uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:80"]
```

GitHub workflow,

CI.yml:

```
name: Docker Image CI

env:
  CONTAINER_NAME: my-use-case

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

concurrency:
  group: ${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.head_ref || github.run_id }}
  cancel-in-progress: true

permissions:
  id-token: write
  contents: write

jobs:
  integration-tests:
    name: Integration Test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: View directory files
        run: |
          pwd
          echo "$PATH"

      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: "3.11.1"

      - name: Copy Python binaries to Docker context
        run: |
          mkdir -p Python/3.11.1
          cp -r $RUNNER_TOOL_CACHE/Python/3.11.1/* Python/3.11.1

      - name: View directory files
        run: |
          ls -lhR
          echo "$PATH"

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python --version
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip

      - name: View directory files
        run: |
          ls -lhR

      - name: Build & push docker image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          context: .
          push: false
          tags: ${{ env.CONTAINER_NAME }}:${{ github.run_number }}
          file: ./Dockerfile
```

Comment: This question is new but has something relevant to my [old question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/288316/how-to-reduce-the-build-time-of-docker-image-layer-in-github-actions)

Comment: Why do you need the final two `RUN` commands after `COPY . /app`? ("`RUN python -m pip install -U pip`" and "`RUN python3.11 -m pip install ...`")

Comment: @Peilonrayz Yeah, now I realize that I can copy the `requriements.txt` file first, then the `RUN` command, and then the final `COPY . /app` command. Thanks for your details suggestion on my previous question.

Comment: Do you need to compile Python yourself? I usually use one of the pre-built Debian-based Python images. This still allows you to use apt to install software. https://hub.docker.com/_/python

Comment: @NickODell For some specific reasons, I have to do it myself, because I need base image as Ubuntu 22.02 and python 3.11.1, not sure I can find this exact combination of python official image.

Comment: You can just install any version of python you want from deassnakes ppa. An then update python3 to point to it.

Comment: @AjinkyaKamat I have tried that, it is not giving me the exact version like 3.11.1 instead it will give the lastest 3.11.x version.

Comment: If your code depends on the minor version of something you got a bigger problems than speeding up builds on CI.

Comment: @AjinkyaKamat Whilst you're probably right you shouldn't depend on minor versions. Python makes no guarantee the code will work across minor versions. You can just look at the `typing` module in 3.5 which radically changed the internals numerous times across minor versions. Additionally I've seen minor versions introduce bugs. Version pinning to a specific version (minor included) isn't really bad when Python makes no guarantee about minor version compatibility.